# No overload matches this call typescript nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

i want to make a test that some addUser() method have been called and returned value. But i get this error: "`No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 4, '(object: typeof UserController, method: never): SpyInstance<never, never>', gave the following error.`

So my userController.spec.ts where the error is in jest.spyOn(...):

```
import {UserController} from "../../src/modules/Users/Infrastructure/http/controllers";

describe('Users Controllers series ', function () {
    it("should create a new user", async () => {

        const spy = jest.spyOn(UserController, "addUser").mockReturnValueOnce()
    })
});
```

and then userController.ts here

```
import { UserServices} from "../../../domain/services";
import {CreateUSerDTO} from "../../../domain/dto/createUserDTO";
import express from "express";
import { Response} from "../../../../../shared/helpers/response";

export class UserController {


    constructor(private readonly userService: UserServices) {}

     async addUser(req: express.Request, res: express.Response):Promise<Response<CreateUSerDTO>> {
        let dto:CreateUSerDTO = req.body as CreateUSerDTO
        dto = {
            username:dto.username,
            useremail: dto.useremail,
            password: dto.password
        }
        try {
             const result = await this.userService.createUser(dto)
            console.log(res.json(result))
            return Response.ok<CreateUSerDTO>(result)

        }catch (error) {
           return Response.fail<CreateUSerDTO>(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know what's wrong in my code

Answer (score 4):

Root cause of the issue is that you are configuring the spy on the `UserController` constructor while `addUser` is only available on `UserController` instances.

You should either spy on the concrete `UserController` instance or spy on the `UserController` prototype:

```
describe('Users Controllers series ', function () {
    it("should create a new user", async () => {

        const spy = jest.spyOn(UserController.prototype, "addUser").mockReturnValueOnce()
    })
});
```

Comment: @cedric Good to know that it worked well. Please accept the answer if it solves the issue.